# Material-UI Autocomplete input reset when click outside the Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using a basic autocomplete from Material-UI, the options loaded fine and could be able to filter successfully.

However, once we filter the options, just click on outside, filter is cleared and dropdown is sorted/reset.

This is basically causing issue in accessibility issue on Mobile. When we turn android voice over and filter the result, when user try to select the option, it is always picking the option which is not the filtered result. Looking like, the filter rest, and dropdown shuffled. I observe due to the filter is reset, when it is out of focus causing the issue here.
It works fine for autoselect. But in my usecase, I don't want to autoselect.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={["a", "b", "c"]}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} onChange={(e, v) => setState(v)} />
      )}
      value={state}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to the question?

Comment: Please find the code @NearHuscarl export default function App() {
const [state, setState] = useState();
return (
<Autocomplete
options={["a", "b", "c"]}
renderInput={(params) => (
<TextField {...params} onChange={(e, v) => setState(v)} />
)}
value={state}
/>
);
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`freeSolo` prop](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#free-solo) to allow arbitrary input value in the `Autocomplete`:

```
<Autocomplete freeSolo
```

Comment: freeSolo doesn't help in the current use case. When the results filtered, and the user out of focus from autocomplete.. either just click outside of the field/right click, the list is re-sorted and filter has been reset

Comment: @KrisshhGurram I don't quite understand what you mean by re-sorted and reset. the items doesn't get re-sort when you focus again with freeSolo. Do you want the select popover to display even after the user clicks outside?

Comment: I mean for example, if you have options ["a test","b test","c test","d test", "a a test"] when you enter a in the autocomplete text box, the options will be filtered and shows only options contains "a". Now just right click or click outside the text box, the filter is cleared and options will be listed again in alphabetical order. As per the investion, I found onInputChange triggers the event with reset reason which is clearing the filter. In my case, even the user click anywhere outside the textbox, the input value i.e. "a" and filtered list should not be disturbed.

Comment: @KrisshhGurram in the freesolo `Autocomplete` from [this](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#free-solo) section. The first option is `The Shawshank Redemption`, when you enter `star`, you get 3 starwar movie options, click outside or right click, then click the `Autocomplete` again, it still shows that 3 starwar movies again. Isn't that what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for your response. My expecting the behaviour which you have explained above, But it is not working for him. It always clears the filter and options are sorted with full list. Can you share the source code, which is working for you

Comment: @KrisshhGurram the code is from the demo (link in my answer). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2II43.gif) is a gif to show what I mean

Comment: After trying with the latest version, when we set clearOnBlur to false, it is working fine.